# Error booting kernel 4.5.0-rc1 on Encrypted HDD

Tags: kernel, boot, grub2, encryption

I cloned the Git tree of the mainline Linux Kernel and compiled it(`version 4.5.0-rc1`).

After compiling with default configuration (`make defconfig`) I installed it.

In the grub menu I can select this kernel(`4.5.0-rc1`) to boot but after loading the kernel the part comes up where I need to enter my `LUKS` disk encryption key.

After I enter the key it gives me this error.

```
[   23.744123] device-mapper: table: 253:0: crypt: unknown target type
[   23.744153] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: reload ioctl on temporary-cryptsetup-1377 failed: Invalid argument
Failed to setup dm-crypt key mapping for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/6f3b8c27-99fe-41f3-af3d-8d3ac036f23a.
Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher (check syslog for more info).
```

System Information:

```
$ uname -r  
4.2.0-29-generic

$ lsusb_release
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

NOTE: I use Full Disk Encryption (LUKs) and it is on x86-64 architecture.

Thank you.

Comment: You should have used default config that was shipped with your distribution kernel.

Comment: I did. I the config file from /boot and used that. But it made matters only worse. The new kernel did not even ask for the password. It just started running the init script. It ran into an infinite loop.

Comment: Did you build new initramfs for your kernel?

Comment: I don't think so. I did `sudo make modules_install install`. After that in the /boot directory there were 3 new files. Initrd.img-4.5.0-rc1, vmlinuz-4.5.0-rc1 and System.maph4.5.0-rc1

Comment: It sounds like you're using vanilla kernel build commands, but distributions like Ubuntu usually require their own methods of building kernel, making initramfs etc. For initramfs thing, last time I remember there is a command `update-initramfs` which was required to build an initramfs in a "distro" way.

Comment: Yeah. I tried `make-initramfs -u`. Still no result. The same error shows up.

Comment: Where your `make-initramfs` comes from? Is it a new Ubuntu-specific way of creating initramfs?

Comment: It's a huge mistake. I meant `update-initramfs`. On a side note. Is this because of some dm-crypt error ?

Comment: The error message states it clearly, `Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher (check syslog for more info).`. You should check availability of such a cipher in your new kernel, by at least grepping parts of name of cipher in your .config

Comment: The setting fr aes-xts-plain64 is same as it was on my native kernel config file. It was included as a module (m) so I kept it that way itself. However when I added it in the kernel itself (y) the kernel ran into a loop. It did not even ask for the password. Just kept running the init script.